# Rails.cache.fetch produces an error in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rspec

I'm getting `ActionView::Template::Error: RSpec::Mocks::Double#marshal_dump returned same class instance` when running tests that involve `Rails.cache.fetch`. in my config/environments/test.rb I disable caching (I think) with this:

```
config.cache_store = :null_store
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

my caching method takes a proc and does this

```
def use_cached(evaluate_value_proc, key, cache_options)
  Rails.cache.fetch(key, cache_options) do
    evaluate_value_proc.call
  end
end
```

In tests, I expect the cache to miss and the block simply to be called again. What's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: looks fine - what's the spec?

Answer (score 0):

i tested those cases by mock the `exist?` method of `memory_store` to return `false` so that the `fetch` method will call the `block`

```rb
allow(Rails).to receive(:cache).and_return(ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:memory_store))
allow_any_instance_of(ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore).to receive(:exist?).and_return(false)
```